# Isn't using multiple delegates and separating them bad form?

Tags: ios, swift

According to the apple documentation, the correct way to use multiple text fields and setup functions for them is with a switch statement. Isn't that really bad form? I thought you were supposed to keep all your components seperated so that they are easier to debug and to work on a single component without jumping around in the code.

Apple suggests doing this:

````
    switch (textField.tag) {
        case NameFieldTag:
            // do something with this text field
            break;
        case EmailFieldTag:
             // do something with this text field
            break;
        // remainder of switch statement....
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Your title ask if having multiple delegates is bad form. But then you posted code with a single delegate and ask if that is bad. Please clarify your question.

Comment: That depends on how you define component. If you think of the `UITextField` as a component of the view controller, regardless of how many instances there are in that view controller, there you have your separation.

Answer (score 1):

When you have multiple instances of the same type of widget in your View, then those widgets are going to all share the same widget delegate overrides.  So, using the .tag property is one of the ways to tell which instance invoked the delegate method... you could probably look at the value of other properties for the UITextView or whatever is sent as a parameter to the delegate to identify it too, but the .tag works pretty well.  So, no, the example you posted is exactly the way most of us handle this.